# concatenating strings in .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

This may be a dumb question but I can't seem to get it or find it anywhere.

I have a .each function that returns the id's of a bunch of divs on a page and then assigns them a number. I need them to be outputted in a specific format all as one string so I can pass them to a database and use them as "sort_order" values. (I split them through a sproc in my database).

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#updateAllContentButton').click(function() {
    var count = 1;
 jQuery('.CommentaryItem').each(function() {
    var id = GetID(jQuery(this));
        var data_str = (id + ':' + count + '~');
        console.log(data_str);
        count++;
    });
});
```

So that returns each data_str on a separate line but I need it to return it like this:
144:2~145:3~146:4~147:4~148:5 (so on)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and join :

```
jQuery('#updateAllContentButton').click(function() {
    console.log(jQuery('.CommentaryItem').map(function(i) {
        return GetID(jQuery(this)) + ':' + (i+1);
    }).get().join('~'));
});
```

Note that you don't have to count yourself : Most jQuery iteration functions do it for you.

Comment: This syntax can also be called inside a string concatenation (+).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for that. Like this...

```
jQuery('#updateAllContentButton').click(function() {
    var count = 1;
    var arr = [];
 jQuery('.CommentaryItem').each(function() {
    var id = GetID(jQuery(this));
    var data_str = (id + ':' + count + '~');
    arr.push(data_str);
    //console.log(data_str);
    count++;
 });
 console.log(arr.join());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery('#updateAllContentButton').click(function() {
var count = 1;
var data_str = "";
jQuery('.CommentaryItem').each(function() {
var id = GetID(jQuery(this));
    data_str += (id + ':' + count + '~');
    console.log(data_str);
    count++;
});
```

});

Comment: I mean use += on data_str instead of just = :)

Comment: After posting I did try this way but you have to declare data_str before the each loop and it ends up adding an extra ~ at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I've corrected that :) Still the best solution is posted by dystroy :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var data_str = (id + ':' + count + '~');
```

to

```
data_str+ = (id + ':' + count + '~');
```

full code

```
jQuery('#updateAllContentButton').click(function() {
    var count = 1,
        data_str;

    jQuery('.CommentaryItem').each(function() {
        var id = GetID(jQuery(this));
        data_str += (id + ':' + count + '~');
        console.log(data_str);
        count++;
    });
});
```